# volumes in Docker-compose in ECS?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm using volumes so that two containers share a log file (filebeat needs to see log of webserver)

```
   web:
     volumes:
       #Logs are mounted to a relative path. These are also accessed by Filebeat and consumed by the uwsgi module.
       - ./compose/production/logs/uwsgi/:/var/log/uwsgi/
   filebeat:
     restart: always
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./compose/production/filebeat/Dockerfile
       args:
         - VERSION=${VERSION}
     image: filebeat
     volumes:
       - ./compose/production/logs/uwsgi/:/var/log/uwsgi/
```

I understand `./compose/production/logs/uwsgi` is directory at the host machine. (which is the machine I'm running `docker-compose up`

When I deploy this to production, I'll create images and upload to `ECS` 
I don't know how the images are run over there at ECS but I haven't configured any `docker-compose` related settings. so it must be run as plain docker images.

I'm concerned that then the shared volumes are not going to be shared at production ECS.

How can I make the two containers share a file/directory when run? 
Or should I combine the service and create 1 image?

- I can think of creating a separate volume but I'm not sure how it is going to handle if there are multiple web containers, they are going to share a log file and it isn't what I want.
- If I combine services, and install filebeat in web service (via apt).

  - it tends to create monolith service which I'd like to avoid if possible
- I'm not sure if my current setting is going to work at the production (ECS) or not, is there a way to experiment without deploying to ECS?